# google compute engine instances timezone changed to UTC automatically

Tags: timezone, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I'm a new user of GCE instances.

I created instances a week ago and changed timezone to Asia/Shanghai by commands below:
cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Shanghai /etc/localtime

Then yesterday, I found that my system timezone changed to UTC automatically and /etc/localtime was changed. So I run the command above agina. Until now it's OK.

After that I checked many resources and export TZ='Asia/Shanghai'. But I still not know if it's the root cause or not.

Also I find that someone adds xen.independent_wallclock=1 in sysctl.conf file to maintain independent times. But it's for Xen VM and I'm not sure if it's useful for GCE.

Could anyone please take a look at it ?

Comment: Off topic for StackOverflow, but in general - server instances *should* use UTC.  A well designed server application should not rely on the time zone setting of the server anyway.

Answer (score 10):

I've found a more user friendly approach [here](http://andrewcmaxwell.com/2014/07/how-to-change-the-timezone-on-google-cloud-debian-virtual-machines)

Go root user

```
sudo -s
```

and use

```
dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

This will bring up a GUI which will guide you to change your timezone information

Answer (score 4):

To make the permanent change edit $HOME/.profile or $HOME/.bash_profile appending the line and then log out and log in again:

TZ='Asia/Shanghai'; export TZ

Comment: Thanks. I've done it. Until now it's OK. If timezone changed again automatically, I will update the info.

Comment: If you want this change to be permanent for all the users you can add this to /etc/profile.

Answer (score 2):

for windows users open powershell as admin and type `TZUtil.exe /s "<your new time zone>"`.
to see a list of all available time zones type `TZUtil.exe /l`.
for more info type `TZUtil.exe /?`.